# Google maps marker not showing up

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-markers

My map is showing perfectly, the only thing I am missing is the marker and title. Can someone view my code and see why my markers are not showing up?

My code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6078568,13.0126611),
      zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map_392"),
        mapOptions);
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6078568,13.0126611)
        var marker = new google.maps.marker({
            position:point,
            map:map,




        });


  }

</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marker is an object constructor so you need to use the proper (capitalized) name:

> var marker = new google.maps.Marker();

That will create the marker on your map, but if you want it to have a title then you will need to add the "title" property as well:

```
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6078568, 13.0126611),
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map_392"), mapOptions);

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6078568, 13.0126611);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map,
            title: "The title for the marker."
        });
    }
```

Comment: grandham thank you, the marker is showing now but still no title, I just copied and pasted your code

Comment: Oke its working what about if I want to add an html? Like this;  html: "<center>The top-secret location premier<br />company adress<hr />0771 - 222 222<br />info@email.com</center>"

Comment: The title simply appears as a tooltip if you hover over the marker. Are you sure that isn't happening, or are you meaning something else by 'title'?

Comment: @Abel, what you're now wanting is an infowindow. Check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows